# ¿Como puedo reemplazar valores en una columna con valores de otra si se cumplen condiciones?

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Reemplzar valor de `column Q` con valor de `column U`, si en `column U` hay cédula y `column R` es igual a "`NNNNNNNNNNN`"

Tengo este código:

```
Dim Rng As Range, InputRng As Range, ReplaceRng As Range
Set InputRng = ActiveSheet.Range("Q4", Range("Q4").End(xlDown))    
Set a = Range("Q4", Range("Q4").End(xlDown))
Set b = Range("U4", Range("U4").End(xlDown))
Set ReplaceRng = Union(a, b).Select

Range("U2").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Rng In ReplaceRng.Columns(1).Cells
     Rng.Offset(0, 1).Select
    If Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value <> "" And InputRng.Offset(0, 1).Value = "NNNNNNNNNNN" Then        
        Rng.Replace what:=Rng.Value, replacement:=Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Cuando dices *si en column U hay cédula* a que te refieres? a que haya datos? Y otra cosa. Para hacer esto, no necesitas VBA, una simple formula en columna Q te podría servir.

Comment: Hola Elier. si, me refiero a que haya datos. Que formula podria aplicar para que reemplace el valor de cada celda de la columna Q por el dato de la columna U?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sé la cantidad de celdas que haya, en caso de que sean muchísimas esto se puede ralentizar y entonces te recomiendo utilizar un `Array` para agilizar todo esto. No obstante esto debería ayudarte:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Reemplazar()

    Dim C As Range, LastRow As Long, Criteria1 As String, Valor1 As String

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    Criteria1 = "NNNNNNNNNNN"

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NombreDeTuHoja")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each C In .Range("Q2:Q" & LastRow)
            If .Cells(C.Row, "U") <> vbNullString Then 'asumo que simplemente quieres que haya datos en la Columna U
                If .Cells(C.Row, "R") = Criteria1 Then 'aquí comprobamos si la columna R cumple el criterio
                    C = .Cells(C.Row, "U") 'en caso de que las dos condiciones se cumplan, la Q = U
                End If
            End If
        Next C
    End With

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With    

End Sub
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Damian, me fue muy util